# New to Cron Jobs - and Cron Job not running?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I'm terribly new to cron jobs, but one of the wordpress plugins I'm using relies on one to function the way we want it to (automatic reporting instead of manual).

It's telling me to go start a cron job and give it the command

```
wget --quiet /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION
```

Okay, I did that, and I set it every minute so the whole command looks like this

```
(* * * * *) wget --quiet /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION
```

of course, the query string isn't `THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION`, and it's actual name is all lower case.

But it doesn't seem to be running?

**Some More Info:**

- We are using wordpress on **http://domain.com**
- We need the cron to run on all subdomains - **http://test.domain.com**
- The Cron Job doesn't need to run on the main site
- We are using CPanel

I'm not sure what a `--quiet` cron job is, and I'm also not sure of the difference between like `wget` and `curl`, again I know 'zero' about cron jobs

Let me know if you need any more information

**EDIT:** I removed the `--quiet` and got this in my email spam folder: 
" /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=repagent_email_reports: Scheme missing. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs are nothing mysterious. All a cron job is, is a time interval and a shell command. At every time interval, the shell command will be run.

The cron job you have supplied here consists of these two parts:

- `(* * * * *)` denotes the time interval. This is five fields separated by a space. The fields denote, in order: minute, hour, day, month, and weekday. If you specified a number in one of the fields, such as `1` in the minute field, it would only run the cron job when the current minute was `1`. A `10` in the `hour` field would only run when the current hour was `10`. A `*` means that any value is fine. Five stars means to run the command once every minute of every hour or every day of every month. Curiously, if you had `* 10 * * *` it would run the cron job every minute of the 10th hour of every day of every month.
- `wget --quiet /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION` is the shell command to run. This is just a shell command. You can test the shell command outby running it in a shell.

The problem you have is that your arguments to `wget` are not correct. The `--quiet` argument to `wget` means that it will not produce much output. The `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION` is the address to request. `wget` is failing because `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION` is not a valid address - the schema (`http:`) and hostname (`test.domain.com`) are missing.

You can fix your cron job by changing it to:

```
(* * * * *) wget --quiet http://test.domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=THE_PLUGINS_FUNCTION
```

You will need to add a new cron job for every subdomain you want to run this command on.

You can check to make sure you have your `wget` command working correctly by pasting it in a shell and running it. Once you know it is working fine, add it as a cron job and it should work just fine.